# Sphinx search filter by category

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

I have a list of items with different categories. An item could be in multiple categories, so I have 3 tables: items / categories / connections

I need to filter / count the search results:

- category1 (100 items)
- category2 (90 items)
- category3 (80 items)
- etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recently made this

http://www.nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example6-withcomments.phps

which is a documented example doing pretty much what you ask.

Comment: btw, this answer is about creating the front end. It assumes you already have a working index, with the category stored in an attribute. Do you? Also just realised you said can be in multiple categories. Which complicates matters slightly. The example doest cope with MVAs

Comment: I found an example that seems to be similar with my needs and is also solved by you :)
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=6805

Comment: I used group_id with ord to apply the filter in the category page.
Exists the posibility tu use SetGroupBy with ord? In need it for the side categories counts.
In this context: $counts = array();
 
 foreach ($res['matches'] as $doc_id => $row)
 {
         $counts[$row['attrs']['@groupby']] = $row['attrs']['@count'];
 }
 
 $ids = array_keys($counts);